# Ubuntu 18.10 night light stuck on

Tags: display, 18.10, ubuntu-gnome, colors, color-management

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 to 18.10. Everything works fine, except on start-up the *night light* feature causes the screen to start to fade immediately. I can then find no way of turning it off.

- Switching it off explicitly in display settings doesn't work.
- I have tried switching from 'Sunset to Sunrise' to manual, and adjusted the timings. This *sometimes* leads to flashing of the screen between the night and day modes, but this soon settles down after a couple of seconds back to night mode.
- I have tried adjusting the settings in dconf-editor, such as the temperature, just to make it usable whilst it's stuck on, to no effect
- I have tried disabling and uninstalling any gnome extensions that may be messing with the display, but none of these has fixed the issue.

Just to confirm, this functionality worked flawlessly in 18.04.

**Edit:** still an issue after further upgrade to 19.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this turned out to be because I had [f.lux](https://justgetflux.com/linux.html) installed as well (which I had [forgotten about...](https://giphy.com/gifs/the-simpsons-homer-simpson-doh-8WdsK61D9YOOc)), and the native night mode was conflicting with it. This conflict wasn't present in my previous Ubuntu version (18.04).

[Uninstalling f.lux](https://superuser.com/questions/915707/how-to-uninstall-flux-on-linux) fixed the issue.